# load html page into flex textarea

Tags: html, apache-flex, url

Hello I would like to show some textcontent from a website in a textarea box in flex.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.core.Application;
        import flash.net.URLLoader;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.controls.Text;
        import mx.controls.Alert; 

        [Bindable]
        private var xmlText:String;

        private function serviceResult(event:ResultEvent):void 
        {
        myTextArea.text = event.result.contents.content;
        }

        private function init():void{
        listContents.send();
        }
    ]]> 
</mx:Script>

<mx:HTTPService id="listContents" url="http://theurl.com" result="serviceResult(event)"/>

<mx:TextArea id="myTextArea" text="{xmlText}" />
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I have done like this b4 but with flash CS3 by using URLLoader and URLRequest
so it's the same idea in flex try using this concept

```
public function sendSQLQuery(aspURL:String, variables:URLVariables, returnSQLXMLCallback:Function):void
        {
           var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(aspURL);          
           myXMLURL.data = variables;          
           myXMLURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;        
           var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();           
           //Define the event handlers to listen for success and failure
           myLoader.addEventListener ( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError );
           myLoader.addEventListener ( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, handleHttpStatus );
           myLoader.addEventListener ( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleSecurityError );
           myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
           myLoader.addEventListener("complete", returnSQLXMLCallback);         
           myLoader.load(myXMLURL);
        }
```

and i recieve the returned page in XML format and then parse it

Comment: public function returnSQLXMLCallback(event:Event):void
     {
      
     }

can you fill me in what to put in there?

Comment: sorry i already have it (var x:xml=new XML(event.target.data); 

thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

A shorthand way:

```
<mx:TextArea htmlText="{xmlText}" />    
<mx:String id="xmlText" source="data.xml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .htmlText property of your TextArea control.  See here, from the Flex docs:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextArea.html#htmlText

That should work, but keep in mind the HTML-rendering capabilities of Flex controls are still quite rudimentary; you won't get much in the way of styling or formatting (hence the number of questions on StackOverflow on this very topic), but the basics should work for ya.